# Boost preprocessor library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

I'm having some trouble expanding to the base value

```
# include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>

#define REL_ITERATION_1 1
#define REL_FRAME_ITERATION(i) BOOST_PP_CAT(REL_ITERATION_, i)
#define REL_ITERATION_PARAMS_2 REL_FRAME_ITERATION(1)
#define REL_FRAME1(i)           BOOST_PP_CAT(REL_ITERATION_PARAMS_, i)
#define REL_FRAME2(i)           REL_ITERATION_PARAMS_##i
REL_FRAME1(2)
REL_FRAME2(2)
```

Here's the output.

```
BOOST_PP_CAT(REL_ITERATION_, 1)
1
```

Does anyone have any idea why the first call is not the same as the second? I thought I had a handle on using the preprocessor, but I just don't get this. :(

Comment: How do I accept it?  Oh, click on the check mark.  It says I can accept it in a couple of days.

Comment: There is a green check symbol on the left side of the answer. Click it. Also, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Yeah, it's not green.  It turns green when you click it.  But it won't allow me till tomorrow for some reason.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  I missed the part in the documentation where it says if it expands to a BOOST_PP_CAT() macro, it won't expand it.

Doh!